# Sending SignalR alert messages from controller actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I seem to have a problem sending an alert (toast) message from a controller action using SignalR. Unless I add a `Thread.Sleep()` after the send call, I never see the message. Inevitably, the send call occurs before `return View()`, so I imagine the alert is visible for a millisecond on the previous view, until the new one is served.

My first, rough solution is to use a timer to keep sending the message, until I get an acknowledgement.

This solution stinks. What else can I do? I can have the 'receiving' pages poll the server to see if they have any alerts, but that defeats the purpose of SignalR.

But then, maybe SignalR isn't suited to my case and I should just send the alerts as json strings on the model.

From the `Login` action:

```
....
//ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
AlertsHub.ShowClientAlert(new Alert(AlertLevel.Error, "Invalid login attempt."));
return View(model);
```

The hub:

```
public class AlertsHub : Hub
{
    private static Alert pendingAlert;
    static Timer pollTimer;

    internal static void ShowClientAlert(Alert alert)
    {
        if (pendingAlert != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        pendingAlert = alert;
        pollTimer = new Timer(_ => SendAlert(pendingAlert), null, 0, 500);
    }

    static private void SendAlert(Alert alert)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlertsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.ShowAlert(alert.Level.ToString(), alert.Message, alert.Title);
    }

    [HubMethodName("AlertReceived")]
    public void AlertReceived(Guid alertId)
    {
        pollTimer.Dispose();
        pendingAlert = null;
    }
}
```

From the JS:

```
var toast;

$(function () {
    if (typeof toast != 'undefined' && toast != null) {
        showToast(toast);
        toast = null;
    }

    var alertsProxy = $.connection.alertsHub;

    alertsProxy.client.showAlert = function(alertId, level, message, title) {
        toast.alertId = alertId;
        toast.level = level;
        toast.message = message;
        toast.title = title;
    };

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log('Could not Connect!');
        });
});

function showToast(toast) {
    switch (toast.level.toLowerCase()) {
    case "success":
        toastr.success(toast.message, toast.title);
        break;
    ...
    }

    alertsProxy.server.AlertReceived(alertId)
        .done(function() {
            console.log("Alert '" + alertId + "' acknowledged.");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Acknowledgement of alert '" + alertId + "' failed.");
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant bits of code? (Controller + JS if you have both)

Comment: @PedroG.Dias The code is in a bit of a state of flux at the moment, but I'll just show my experimental work in progress. It still needs a lot of work.